# Motif 1.2 X11 on using RowColumn widget inside a ScrolledWindow

Tags: c, widget, x11, motif

I have a Motif client (running it on Linux).  The client displays an array of buttons to the user in a tabular fashion.  Obvious choice is the RowColumn widget.  I want scrollbars around the array of buttons so I created a ScrolledWidget and place the RowColumn widget inside.  I also place a Frame widget around the Row column widget to make it stand out.

Now, the problem.   I want to put a button OUTSIDE the array of widgets for Quit.  Problem is it not displaying the button.  Is this doable?

Any sample code to do this is appreciated.

Comment: Post YOUR code and you will more likely get a helpful answer.

Comment: will post it tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 1):

XmForm contains:
   XmPushButton (exit)
   XmScrolledWindow contains:
     XmFrame contains
        XmRowColumn contains:
          array of XmPushButtons

Set up the connections for the XmForm to place the exit button and scrolled window appropriately.

Comment: who is the XmScrolledWindow's parent widget?  toplevel? or the XmForm?